# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Getting the error "WARN  PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WebApp_Local/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"

I am trying for the hello world spring maven project the below are my files while running the application cant able to find the controller methods

Please help me , i am new to the Area and struggling here

DispatcherServlet

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.abc.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue =      "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("in controller");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
    }
  }
```

below is the error log

```
2015-07-20 21:31:00 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with      name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/WebApp_Local/hello]
2015-07-20 21:31:00 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:294 - Looking up handler method for path /hello
2015-07-20 21:31:00 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:302 - Did not find handler method for [/hello]
2015-07-20 21:31:00 WARN  PageNotFound:1136 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WebApp_Local/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2015-07-20 21:31:00 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:997 - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Make sure name of your Spring configuration file is `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and placed inside `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Yes it is placed inside WEB-INF only

Comment: try to remove `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in your xml config

Comment: i tired removing <mvc:default-servlet-handler />  but couldnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally identified the issue for the problem, its because my Controller java file are not found in the target folder and hence dipatcher servlet cant able to identify the controller mapping methods.

Thanks for the comments.